# Queuing tasks with prioritization rules

Tags: python, nginx, flask, celery, scheduled-tasks

This is a more general question on how the solution could be designed.

The goal is to have an **API** which would take some a text or a list of texts, process it and return transformed ones. How should I approach it so that whenever a text is requested, all the requests that contains list of texts would wait and one text would be processed first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit generic, therefore I'm going to answer with a stack that I developed in a past project. I would use the redis-server function of streaming(https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro). You can have a stream for a list of texts and a stream for texts, and when your algorithm is searching for new tasks he first checks if the stream of the list of texts has any pending package. I recommend the usage of redis-server because is a robust solution, having access to a server dedicated for this service, instead of using celery. But I have never used celery for this purpose, and can't advocate for him on this topic.

Comment: Seems like a viable solution. It handles the part of the algorithm where it consumes the input. As for returning the result, did you introduced additional queue that was responsible for result?

Comment: A queue responsible for the result? What do you mean?

Comment: e.g. there is a flask app, that user submits some data. Data is processed through queues and then needs to get back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

In general you would have a heap (priority queue) of requests in line. Your API can fetch highest-priority requests from this heap.

In this particular case, if all you need is `str`s first and `list`s second, define your priority function like `lambda x: 2 if isinstance(x, str) else 1`.

Note that this does not take into account of potential timeouts.. if you have lots of `str` requests, the `list` ones could have to wait a while.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But would prioritization be defined on fetching requests or something like celery be better used? (I am not familiar with it yet, so not sure if that would be a good use case)

Comment: Sure. I over-simplified this and wasn't thinking of production.